# Showing a dialog box with contents of choosing file and camera

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

i want to open a dialog box that gives me two option.

1- Choose file from SD Card
2- Take a snapshot from Camera

Right now i am using this code

```
 receipt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
         {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(RECEIPT_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            Dialog dialog = null;
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
 case RECEIPT_DIALOG_ID:
                    builder.setTitle("Choose your file");
                        dialog = builder.create();
                      return dialog;
                    }
```

Now, how can i add these two options.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it provides both the options

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Memory Card"};

builder.setTitle(R.string.pic_option);
                    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.camera_icon);
                    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                          launchCamera(item);
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();
```

and the Function launchCamera(item) is here

```
public void launchCamera(int id){

            switch (id) {
            case 0:
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                ((Activity)getParent()).startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);
                break;
            case 1: 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                ((Activity)getParent()).startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: how can i pass the value to id? 0,1 how can i pass?

Comment: sorry , plz check my edited answer #CharSequence[] items = {"Camera", "Memory Card"};

Comment: and the application is closing unexpectedly saying that null pointer error

Comment: Well, right now i have clicked a button. It shows a dialog box and then i click on camera or memory card. It both gives error

Comment: you didn't answer my last question that are you override the onActivityResult method for handle startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
for more info look this example http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Comment: one more good example here http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/

Answer (score 0):

Use this directly in your method.It will show 2 buttons on dialog.

```
    Dialog dialog;
    dialog = new Dialog(getParent());
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.camdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("         Select the Image");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    sdCard = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.sdCard);
    camDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.camDialog);
    dialog.show();
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
            new AlertDialog.Builder(menu)
                .setTitle("Choose your file")
                .setMessage("Your msg")
                .setPositiveButton("Choose file from SD Card",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                    // Your code
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Take a snapshot from Camera",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                //Your code
                            }
                        }).show();
```